# How to determine when a FlatList has finished displaying data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that has contents that are rendered depending on a category. Switching between these categories causes some really choppy behaviour. So I was wondering if there is a way I can set a state `isLoading` initially to true and then to false when the FlatList is ready to display the data?

Answer (score 0):

by default the `FlatList` renders only the elements that are currently being shows on the screen.

If you're navigating between screens with React Native Navigate `navigate`, those screens are being put on a stack, and their processing is in the background, ideally you can use `replace` to leave only 1 screen on this stack (this one you want is currently viewing).

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function CategoryOne({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      //FlatList 1
      //onPress={navigation.replace('CategoryTwo')}
    </View>
  );
}

function CategoryTwo({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      //FlatList 2
      //onPress={navigation.replace('CategoryOne')}
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="CategoryOne">
        <Stack.Screen name="CategoryOne" component={CategoryOne} />
        <Stack.Screen name="CategoryTwo" component={CategoryTwo} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

you can see detailed documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating